# Logout - Go back to Login Page

Tags: ios, swift, segue

My app is structure as shown. [image: Structure]

In my `ProfileViewController` which is one of the tabs, there is a logout button.

I want to pop out back to the `RegisterViewController`.

If the user is already registered, I bypass the register screen in the `App Delegate` as shown

```
if (prefs.boolForKey("registered")){
       self.window?.rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("tabBarViewController")
} else { // there is no current user
            // set up app for new or non logged in user
       self.window?.rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("registerViewController")
}
```

I am not sure if that will affect how to navigate back as it is setting the `rootViewController`.

Comment: You can't navigate back since the `RegisterViewController` isn't in the navigation stack.  You can just set the window's `rootViewController` to the `RegisterViewController` like you would on app launch.

Answer (score 0):

In the past I've structured apps to always go through the sign in views. Then I run an auto-authenticating action to push previously authed users to go through to the logged in part of the app. Then when a user wishes to log out I just use a unwind segue to pop back out to the login portion of the app.

Here's a guide to unwind segues by the Ray Wenderlich team: https://www.raywenderlich.com/113394/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-2

Hope this helps!